# Difference in techniques for setting a stubbed method's return value with Rhino Mocks

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks, stubbing

What is the main difference between these following two ways to give a method some fake implementation?

I was using the second way fine in one test but in another test the behaviour can not be achieved unless I go with the first way.

so (the first),

```
using (test.Record()) //test is MockRepository instance
{
 service.GetUser("dummyName");
 LastCall.Return(new LoginUser());
}
```

vs (the second).

```
service.Stub(r => r.GetUser("dummyName")).Return(new LoginUser());
```

---

**Edit**

The problem is that the second technique returns null in the test, when I expect it to return a new LoginUser.  The first technique behaves as expected by returning a new LoginUser.  All other test code used in both cases is identical.

```
[TestFixture]
public class AuthorizationTest
{
    private MockRepository test;
    private IMembershipService service;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        test = new MockRepository();
        service = test.Stub<IMembershipService>();

        using (test.Record())
        {
            service.GetUser("dummyName");
            LastCall.Return(new LoginUser());
        }

        //service.Stub(r => r.GetUser("dummyName")).Return(new LoginUser()); 
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetCurrentUser_UserIsAuthenticated_ReturnsCurrentUser()
    {
        var authStub = new AuthorizationStub_SetCurrentUserAuthenticated(service, true);

        LoginUser u = authStub.GetCurrentUser();
        Assert.That(u != null);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        service = null;
        test = null;
    }
}
```

Could it be something to do with the overload in the interface perhaps?

```
public interface IMembershipService
{
    bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword);
    LoginUser GetUser(string username);
    LoginUser GetUser(object providerUserKey);
    string ResetPassword(string username);
    bool ValidateUser(string username, string password);
}
```

The line causing the problem in the method under test is:

```
LoginUser currentUser = _repository.GetUser(identity.Name);
```

In debug mode, identity.Name is never null and is always "dummyName"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the second method is the new [AAA syntax](http://ayende.com/blog/archive/2008/05/16/rhino-mocks--arrange-act-assert-syntax.aspx), and is the preferred method.  Perhaps you could expand on the problems you had using the AAA syntax, and you might be able to get help fixing that issue.

EDIT:

Are you sure that the method is being called with that parameter?  What happens if you use

```
 service.Stub(r => r.GetUser(Arg<String>.Is.Anything)).Return(new LoginUser());
```

do you get anything returned?

What if you set an expectation rather than just stubbing it and then verify the expectation, might that give you some more information?

```
service.Expect(r => r.GetUser(Arg<String>.Is.Anything)).Return(new LoginUser());
service.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

EDIT2:

ok I did a bit of testing and it seems that it is the way you are creating your stub object.  I assume that the way you are using is for the old style and that you need to use this for the new style:

```
service = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMembershipService>();
```

When I changed to this I can run the tests and get them to pass.  I'm not certain of the exact difference between using the static method to generate the stub and using the test `MockRepository` instance.  Maybe someone else can explain the ins and outs of it.

Anyway for completeness here is the code I ran which worked:

```
[TestFixture]
public class AuthorizationTest
    {
    private IMembershipService service;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
        {
        service = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMembershipService>();
        service.Stub(r => r.GetUser("dummyName")).Return(new LoginUser()); 
        }

    [Test]
    public void GetCurrentUser_UserIsAuthenticated_ReturnsCurrentUser()
        {
        var authStub = new AuthorizationStub_SetCurrentUserAuthenticated(service, true);

        LoginUser u = authStub.GetCurrentUser();
        Assert.That(u != null);
        }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
        {
        service = null;
        }
    }

public class AuthorizationStub_SetCurrentUserAuthenticated
    {
    private readonly IMembershipService m_service;
    private readonly bool m_b;

    public AuthorizationStub_SetCurrentUserAuthenticated (IMembershipService service, bool b)
        {
        m_service = service;
        m_b = b;
        }

    public LoginUser GetCurrentUser ()
        {
        return m_service.GetUser ("dummyName");
        }
    }

public interface IMembershipService
    {
    bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword);
    LoginUser GetUser(string username);
    LoginUser GetUser(object providerUserKey);
    string ResetPassword(string username);
    bool ValidateUser(string username, string password);
    }

public class LoginUser
    {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples. Its weird, the test fails still unless there is the presence of the stub with record and lastcall.  When that stub is in there AND I also include your service.Expect and service.VerifyAllExpectations it passes.  If i swap the record and lastcall stub with your stub example it fails.

Comment: I posted my interface, maybe the problem is due to the overload and the stub picks the wrong method?

Comment: No, renamed one of the methods and the problem is still there.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and for your efforts im going to give you something decent... +125 (in 24hrs).  Still wonder why the instance method makes that much difference but anyway...